# How do I use evaluation for parameters in stored procedure?

Tags: t-sql

I need to execute following stored procedure where `@Table_temp` is supposed to a concatenation of `@Table` and `temp`. So how I properly parametrize this?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[swap_Collect]
@Table  varchar,
@UniqueColumn varchar
AS

BEGIN
    IF (OBJECT_ID(@Table) IS NOT NULL )
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Table_temp as varchar 
        SET @Table_temp= @Table + '_temp'
      DELETE FROM @Table where @UniqueColumn in (Select @UniqueColumn from @Table_temp)
      INSERT INTO @Table SELECT * from PRODUCTS_temp
      SELECT 1
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN 
      SELECT * INTO @Table from Collects_temp
      SELECT 1
    END
END
```

[image]

Comment: Where does `@MyTable` come from? If it's a table variable, it's not declared. If it's a variable representing a table name, it's not being assigned a value anywhere.

Comment: It complains about `@Table` not `@MyTable`. I correct second reference. I need table name to be value of input parameter called @Table which is passed to stored procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although several SQL dialects do, SQL Server doesn't support variables as object names. You have to work around this using dynamic SQL.

Comment out the `EXEC` lines and uncomment the `PRINT` lines to validate the dynamic SQL is producing the appropriate statements.

I also noticed that all of your `varchar` declarations are missing the length parameters. That makes them all [one character long](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61869748/5790584), which certainly isn't your intention. Table names are defined using `sysname`, which is nearly identical to `NVARCHAR(128)`, so I switched to that.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[swap_Collect]
  @Table  varchar,
  @UniqueColumn varchar
AS

-- Moving the variable declaration so we can use them in both the IF and the ELSE
DECLARE @Table_temp as varchar = @Table + '_temp'
       ,@SQL varchar(500)
       ,@NL varchar(2) = CONCAT(CHAR(10),CHAR(13)); 
        -- This is a new line character to make the dynamic code more readable.

BEGIN
  IF (OBJECT_ID(@Table) IS NOT NULL ) --The variable is fine here.
    BEGIN

      -- Delete from the base table here.      
      SET @SQL = CONCAT(
        'DELETE FROM ',QUOTENAME(@Table), @NL,
        'WHERE ',QUOTENAME(@UniqueColumn),
        ' IN (SELECT ',QUOTENAME(@UniqueColumn),' FROM ', QUOTENAME(@Table_temp),');');
      --PRINT @SQL;
      EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;

      -- Insert into the base table here.
      SET @SQL = CONCAT(
        'INSERT INTO ', QUOTENAME(@Table), @NL,
        'SELECT * FROM ', QUOTENAME(@Table_temp),';');
      --PRINT @SQL;
      EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;

      SELECT 1
    END
  ELSE
      BEGIN 
        -- Insert into the base table here.
        -- SELECT...INTO only works if the target table doesn't exist. Since @Table does exist
        -- we'll use INSERT INTO instead. 
        SET @SQL = CONCAT(
          'INSERT INTO ', QUOTENAME(@Table), @NL,
          'SELECT * FROM ', QUOTENAME(@Table_temp),';');
        --PRINT @SQL;
        EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;

        SELECT 1
      END
END
```

Since this uses it, here's a good reference. [Dos and Don'ts of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dos-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql)

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].swap_Collect(
@Table as varchar(MAX),
@UniqueColumn as varchar(MAX))
AS
BEGIN
    IF (OBJECT_ID(@Table) IS NOT NULL )
    BEGIN

       DECLARE @query nvarchar(MAX)
       set @query = 'DELETE FROM '+  @Table + ' where ' + @UniqueColumn  + ' in (Select ' +  @UniqueColumn + ' from ' + @Table +  '_temp)' 
       set @query = @query + 'INSERT INTO ' + @Table + ' SELECT * from ' +  @Table + '_temp'
       EXEC sp_executesql @query
       SELECT 1
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN 
       set @query = 'SELECT * INTO ' + @Table + ' from ' + @Table + '_temp'
       print @query
       EXEC sp_executesql @query
       SELECT 1
     END
END
```